# How to make this slow nested SQL Case Query faster

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of 'Contacts' that includes fields like Name, Surname, DOB etc.

I am trying to create an SQL View of this which also includes a field called 'ProspectiveNews'. This field will essentially contain one of 4 classification codes (or blank) depending on a match in criteria from another View.

A contact can have numerous records in this other View with different YearLevels.

In this other View the contacts ID could appear in one of two columns: [ContactID] or [ContactSpouseID] where another column, ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry'

Then there are some records where ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry' where the ContactID column contains their EnquiryID instead so it needs to use that.

Hence the 3 checks for each classification code.

Here is the code though it **takes about 2min to run. That's the problem - it is too slow.** What could I do to make this quicker?

**Code summary:**

IF Contact has a record(s) from another View that is(are) only YearLevel 0 THEN 'K'

IF Contact has a record(s) from another View that is(are) only YearLevel 1-6 THEN '1-6'

IF Contact has a record(s) form another View that is(are) YearLevel 7-12 THEN '7-12'

IF Contact has records that are in YearLevels:

0 AND 1-6

OR

0 AND 7-12

OR

1-6 AND 7-12

THEN 'General'

**Code:**

```html
SELECT

C.ID as ContactID,
ESC.ID as EnquiryID,

CASE WHEN ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry' AND [ContactID] = C.ID)
   )
   OR
   ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry' AND [ContactSpouseID] = C.ID)
   )
   OR
   ( ESC.ContactEnquiryID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 0 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry' AND [ContactID] = C.ID)
   )
 THEN 'K' 

 ELSE 

CASE WHEN ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 0 AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry' AND [ContactID] = C.ID)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 6 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry' AND [ContactID] = C.ID)
   )
   OR
   ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 0 AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry' AND [ContactSpouseID] = C.ID)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 6 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry' AND [ContactSpouseID] = C.ID)
   )
   OR
   ( ESC.ContactEnquiryID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 0 AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel = 0 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry' AND [ContactID] = C.ID)
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 6 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry' AND [ContactID] = C.ID)
   )
   
 THEN '1-6' 

  ELSE 

CASE WHEN ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 6 AND YearLevel < 13 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry' AND [ContactID] = C.ID)
   )
   OR
   ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 6 AND YearLevel < 13 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry' AND [ContactSpouseID] = C.ID)
   )
   OR
   ( ESC.ContactEnquiryID in  (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel > 6 AND YearLevel < 13 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND YearLevel < 7 AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry' AND [ContactID] = C.ID)
   )
 THEN '7-6' 

  ELSE 

CASE WHEN ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   )
   OR
   ( C.ID in  (SELECT  [ContactSpouseID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND ReferenceTable <> 'Enquiry')
   )
   OR
   ( ESC.ContactEnquiryID in  (SELECT  [ContactID]  FROM [Table] WHERE [EnrolDate] > '2016-12-31' AND ReferenceTable = 'Enquiry')
   )

 THEN 'General'

  ELSE ''  END END

 END 
END AS ProspectiveNews
```

Comment: The slow performance is due to the fact you are selecting from [Table] too many times. instead, join a shortlist of [table], maybe aggregated, and use case using the joined fields. If I'll have time I'll write an example later. if you need you join to refer the main table you may want to use OUTER APPLY there are good posts from Itzik Ben-Gan about it or look here: https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event14/Boost_your_T-SQL_with_the_APPLY_Operator

Comment: Thank you for the info. If you have time later i'd love to see the example. I am only new to this.

Comment: Can you please add the schema information? what is the relationship between C, ESC and [Table]?

Comment: @UV thank you. If you like to post your answer i will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@UV

Thank you: The slow performance is due to the fact you are selecting from [Table] too many times. instead, join a shortlist of [table], maybe aggregated, and use case using the joined fields. If I'll have time I'll write an example later. if you need you join to refer the main table you may want to use OUTER APPLY there are good posts from Itzik Ben-Gan about it or look here: sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event14/… – UV

Answer (score 0):

Creating indexes so the engine could optimize those subqueries should do wonders. You should try creating these multiple indexes :

```
ContactID + ReferenceTable + YearLevel + EnrolDate
ContactSpouseID + ReferenceTable + YearLevel + EnrolDate
ReferenceTable + YearLevel + EnrolDate
ReferenceTable + EnrolDate
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have not heard of 'indexes' up until now. Do I add them to this code, or is it a seperate thing I need to make somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, it's a separate thing. Go to the SQL Server Management Studio and enter on the design page of your table. Once there, the right button menu will have the option Indexes/Keys. Then you just have to add those indexes (remember that each index must have several fields on the Columns property to be able to fully optimize your query).

Comment: Index may help but it shouldn't be the solution. having too many indexes may lead to overall bad performance. Every performance issue should first attempt to optimise the query before changing server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The slow performance is due to the fact you are selecting from [Table] too many times. instead, join a shortlist of [table], maybe aggregated, and use case using the joined fields. If I'll have time I'll write an example later. if you need you join to refer the main table you may want to use OUTER APPLY there are good posts from Itzik Ben-Gan about it or look here: sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event14/… – UV

Tahnk you @SSS